# A variant of submodularity

Tags: reference-request

A function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be *submodular* if for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^2$ it holds
$$
f(x \vee y)+f(x \wedge y)\le f(x)+f(y).
$$

In particular, if $x_1 \ge y_1$ and $x_2 \le y_2$, this means that
$$
f(y_1,x_2)+f(x_2,y_1) \le f(x_1,y_1)+f(x_2,y_2),
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\sum_{I\subseteq \{1,2\}}(-1)^{|I|}f(xIy)\ge 0
$$
where $xIy$ is the vector $I$ where we replace the components of $x$ with the components of $y$ in the positions in $I$.

> **Question.** Let us take a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ with the property that
>   $$
> \sum_{I\subseteq \{1,2,3\}}(-1)^{|I|}f(xIy)\ge 0
> $$
>   for all vector $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$. Do such function have a name in the literature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the functions that you've described here, but a related concept is something termed "continuous submodlarity", which is a way to extend the notions of submodularity to $\mathbb{R}^n$. The idea is to use the lattice on $\mathbb{R}_n$ obtained by component-wise partial ordering.

For $i=1, \dots n$, let $\mathcal{X}_i$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. an interval $[a,b]$ or a finite set $\{ 0, 1 \}$) and let $\mathcal{X} = \prod_{i=1}^n \mathcal{X_i} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be the product. Given two vectors $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$, define $x \vee y$ to be a component-wise maximum and $x \wedge y$ to be component-wise minimum. A function $f: \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *continuous submodular* if for all $x,y \in \mathcal{X}$, we have
$$ f(x \vee y) + f(x \wedge y) \leq f(x) + f(y)$$

Here's a [2015 paper by Bach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.00394) which describes these functions in the context of minimization. Here's a [2019 paper by Rad Niazadeh, Tim Roughgarden, and Joshua R. Wang](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.09480) which gives (what I believe is) the first non-trivial maximization algorithm for this function class.